# Java regex- negative lookahead returning a match even when a match shouldn't exist

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
<marker name="my.marker" cachedBy="all" affectedBy="typ1,type2">
<child1>bla</child1>
</marker>
```

What I would like to do is a lookup to identify the first occurrence of `>` using the following condition.

1. Match `>` if the line doesn't have `affectedBy=` attribute available e.g. `affectedBy="type1"` . Because I would like to append it to that line. So I don't want it to be duplicated e.g. `affectedBy="type1,type2", affectedBy="type1,type2"`
2. Match only the firs occurrence of `>` - i.e. not a global match.

I tried the following:

`<(?!=(.*sharedBy=".*"))>`

But it returns a match for `>` even when `affectedBy=` is present. I am sure this might be something wrong in my lookahead logic, but cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to use a XML parser instead of regex.

Comment: The best approach is to match both the tag with _afffectedBy_ attribute and a norml tag. Then in a lambda function, replace as needed.

Comment: What is the name of the tag you're interested in ? Also, what identifiable attributes must exist ? Ex. marker and name="my.marker".

Answer (score 0):

I simply did the following:

1) If anything Matches `affectedBy=.*>` ignore it.

2) Otherwise, find the first group matching `(?=<marker name="my.marker".*)?>`, and then replace `>` with `affectedBy="type1,type2>"`

Didn't want to write XML parsing.